# Is arrayName.length a property of an object? if so which object?

Tags: javascript

The confusing part for me is the dot notation. The dot notation is used for accessing property values of an object, which is also used in finding a length of an array

```
const numbers =[23,45,76,78];
console(numbers.length);
```

Comment: It's part of the Array object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_properties

Comment: An Array is an object.

Comment: It is said, that "_in JS everything is object_", you can do even `'123'.length`.

Comment: @Teemu But this is wrong, of course. Property access causes the MemberExpression on the left to be coerced to an object, i.e. `"123".length` implicitly does `Object("123").length`, which is equivalent to `new String("123").length`. The `Object` call is only idempotent for objects, but not primitives.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That's what it looks like to the programmer. If there's an implicit conversion, I've to re-study the internals, in old days an object was not created, a primitive was passed to a method as `this` after type checking ...

Comment: @Teemu Not sure which “method” you mean, but I’ve just checked: even the first edition of ECMAScript has a [ToObject call](//i.stack.imgur.com/ldGNr.png) in MemberExpressions.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It's called *wrapper type*.

Comment: So, did any of the comments help? I still don’t know what the question really is here. Have you gone through a JS tutorial or reference to familiarize yourself with how JS works?